# How to import directory tree into reference management software and synchronize papers

Tags: mendeley

I previously managed my papers locally in different folders. I'm trying to import the structure of my directory tree into Mendeley with the hope of synchronizing all the papers to Mendeley automatically. However, it failed.

I am wondering how can I import the directory tree together with papers into any reference management software. Besides, I hope that the locally added paper can be automatically synchronized to the software as well.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way round to import local papers into a literature management software and synchronize them online. The software I used is Zotero and two add-ons are required: a) ZotFile and b) Folder Import for Zotero.

Folder Import for Zotero is responsible for importing all your papers and the structure of your repository into Zotero. Once you import all the folders and papers, ZotFile can help with rename and synchronizing using cloud services such as Dropbox, One-drive etc. (cloud service setting required)

New papers can be added either by using Zotero Connector online or imported into Zotero locally by dragging papers into the app windows. After clicking "Rename attachments" for each paper, these papers will be automatically renamed and moved to the clound folder, and synchronized.